# Mute YouTube sound in Delphi TWebBrowser

Tags: javascript, delphi, youtube, browser, mute

I'm coding a small Video Previewing tool in Delphi 2010, but I want to mute the videos programmatically, because as I said, it's for previews.

I've tried several versions of this code, but it always results in a script error, and in the end it's unable to do it.

```
WebBrowser1.ControlInterface.Document.QueryInterface(IHtmlDocument2, doc);
doc.parentWindow.execScript( 'document.getElementById("movie_player").mute()', 'javascript' );
```

Also tried to wait a little longer for the control to complete browsing, but still nothing.

Comment: Which is the error message? can you show the Javascript code where you load th youtube video.

Comment: This is pure javascript question. I wouldn't do this at the webbrowser's side. And the answer might [be here](http://www.faisalkaleem.com/api/how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-mute-using-js-api.html).

Comment: @RRUZ The error is something about the object not having a member "mute()". I also tried setVolume(0), and still, nothing.
@daemon_x It really isn't a js question. If I try to run the code manually in any browser on my computer, it works perfectly. I can't see the reason why it doesn't work here. I've also tried using `WebBrowser1.Navigate( 'javascript:blabla' );`, and still receiving the same problem.

Comment: @Matt - maybe I don't get your question right but if you want to play all of your videos muted why don't you just include the javascript code from my link above to the HTML page and just navigate there ?

Comment: @daemon_x Yes, that could be a solution. But even if I decide to do that in the end, I still wouldn't be satisfied. ;-)

Comment: I guess error message is `Cannot convert document.getElementById("movie_player") to object`

Comment: I think that is right, yes. But I don't see why it should do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call your code in TWebBrowser's [OnDocumentComplete](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnDocumentComplete) event. This event is fired when the document inside is fully loaded, so the object, if it's expected to be there, is already downloaded and is present. Without showing of your JavaScript code I can't tell you more.

But I would do it differently. I would implement code like [this one](http://www.faisalkaleem.com/api/how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-mute-using-js-api.html) directly into your navigated web page. It can mute the sound immediately in the [onYouTubePlayerReady](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#onYouTubePlayerReady) event handler what means immediately when the YouTube player is fully loaded. It's better than call the function later on because it may produce a short sound burst because of some delay between the TWebBrowser's navigation completion and execution of your code.

Answer (score 0):

reference to youtube API's http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html

I believe that at the time you're trying to mute the video, the "document.getElementById("movie_player")" fails.

try to call it like setTimeout( 'document.getElementById("movie_player")', 10000 ); where 10000 is 10 seconds, or even longer, probably the player needs a couple of seconds to be downloaded.

I would also give it a try in different browsers to see if it's actually something that doesn't work as expected in TWebBrowser.

**EDIT**
I would also give "VLC" a go, it can play swf files locally and remotely, there are interfaces for the VLC libraries, so why not? (:

Comment: I actually did try a setTimeout version, before posting this question, still no luck. I could do it with the VLC libs, yeah, but that would require redistributing them. the WebBrowser control doesn't require anything extra. :-)

Comment: @Matt - moreover TWebBrowser is the wrapper for your Internet Explorer you have on your computer and if you told it worked if you ran it manually then there are only two possibilities: 1) it's called differently from Delphi (what is less presumable); 2) you're calling it too early (try to call it in OnDocumentComplete event). I have no experience with this player but I would say it's fully loaded to the client (so at OnDocumentComplete should movie_player be ready).

Comment: or you could also do a loop with jquery like while( $( "#movie_player" ) == undefined ) { /* do something */ }; see what happens (: -- you might also want to consider the VLC libs, you can easily embed them into your exe as a resource and extract them when app is started, very easy, very fast and clean... but it's entirely up to you.