# Delphi TWebBrowser: muting youtube video or disabling autoplay

Tags: delphi, youtube, autoplay, mute

I read this question: [Mute YouTube sound in Delphi TWebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781980/mute-youtube-sound-in-delphi-twebbrowser) but if I understand correctly, it is used for building my own JS/HTML page of preview youtube videos while I load the actual youtube video page and needs to silence it/disable its autoplay.

How can I either mute or disable the autoplay after loading the youtube video page?

Comment: Download online Embedded WebBrowser and do not suffer. This component is much more flexible than just a webbrowser and contains a lot of settings.

Comment: Thanks but it sounds like using a 5kg hammer to kill a fly :) I just need to silence/disable autoplay videos.

Comment: Whatever you come up with will just stop working on you at some point. I wouldn't recommend TEmbeddedWB or TWebBrowser, instead a fixed self-managed web browser like DCEF, if you actually care if this works.